# Angular - not sending headers in the post request

Tags: angular, http, header, http-headers

I'm making a post request and this is what I got in my service

```js
...

const headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
    .set('Authorization', `Bearer' ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`);

return this.http.post<InitialData>(
    `${this.baseUrl}/api/Customers/InitialData`,
    { headers: headers });

...
```

But I'm getting this error -

> HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401, statusText:
> "Missing autorization header", url: "https://pa-prod-***........"

What Am I doing Wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Create the `headers` in the following way -

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
    .set('Authorization', `Bearer' ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`);
```

and use it as -

```
return this.http.post<InitialData>(url, payload, { headers: headers });
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually `httpHeaders` are immutable.
You can do something like this :

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({
  "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`
});
console.log(headers.get('Content-Type'));
```

then you can pass it to the `http.post`.

Check this out : [Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19044)

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried that way but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

Your http post syntax is wrong. You are passing the headers in place of request body.

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
headers = headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer' ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`);

return this.http.post<InitialData>(
    `${this.baseUrl}/api/Customers/InitialData`,
    dataToPost, 
    {headers: headers}
);
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be a good subject for using an interceptor

1. Create interceptor

**jwt.interceptor.ts**

```typescript
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        // add authorization header with jwt token if available
        let authToken = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
        
        if (authToken) {
           request = request.clone({
             setHeaders: {
                ['Authorization']: authToken
             }
          });
        }

        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

In your **app.module.ts**

```typescript
providers: [
    ...
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true },
]
```

Now for all requests made, if auth token exists it will be added to the request

**NB:** *Check how you have added the auth token. It has an apostrophe `'` that should not be there*

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 major issues in your code:

The first one has been mentionned by [Zam Abdul Vahid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66824278/4314588): you are giving the headers in the 2nd parameter (which is the body of the request), instead of 3rd. If you have no body data to give, you can just put `null` as a second parameter.

The second issue has been mentionned by [programoholic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66823919/4314588), where he explains you that HttpHeaders are immutable, i.e. you can't modify them directly, the `set` method will return the new populated object.

You also have a leftover single quote after `Bearer`, that shoudn't be needed.

So in the end, if you do something like chaining your `set` calls, the following code should work:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8').set('Authorization', `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`);

return this.http.post<InitialData>(
    `${this.baseUrl}/api/Customers/InitialData`,
     null,
    { headers }
);
```